# git merge into the middle of the main commits where feature branch started

Tags: git

I couldn't find any similar questions for this precise requirement.
Assume I have a feature and a main branch.
We have some new commits in the main branch after creating the feature branch.
What I want to do is merge into the main at the precise commit in which feature branch was created, as shown in the image below. In other words, feature commits come before main commits.

[image]

Comment: That means you want to rewrite history of _main_.... which is not a good idea to do on a shared branch. Is it a shared branch?

Comment: @eftshift0, Thanks, Yeah, I know it's not a good idea because we can end up ruining other people's stuff, but it's simply for learning.

Comment: Which commits do main and feature point to? Remember, branches don't represent a tree, but are a pointer to a single commit.

Comment: @evolutionxbox, These two branches point to their most recent commits.

Comment: Side note: you have the arrows pointing *forwards*, from parent commits to their children. This is wrong for Git: internally, all the arrows point *backwards*, from children to parents. Sometimes this doesn't matter, and occasionally it does matter, so it's good to remember that Git works backwards.

Comment: @torek, Thank you; I'm sorry, I forgot that.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean to merge the feature branch *and* apply the changes of the second to last revision of main in a single shot (the way the chart is displaying as the desired result), it will require some hacking

```
git checkout main~2
git merge --no--ff featureBranch
git cherry-pick main~
git reset --soft @~ # set HEAD pointer in merge revision we just created
# changes from main~1 are in index
git commit --amend -m "merge and changes from main~1 in a single revision"
git cherry-pick main
# if you like the result
git branch -f main
git checkout main
```

And that's it.

Answer (score 1):

```
git rebase feature main
git replace --graft $(git rev-list feature..main|tail -1) \
        $(git merge-base feature main@{1} feature
git filter-branch
```

The rebase gets the content you want, the replace sets up the weird ancestry, the filter-branch bakes it in.